# webpack how to exclude node_modules except a folder

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack 4 and I have installed a module with a lot of subfolders, the structure would be:

`/node_modules/my_main_package/what_i_need_to_include`

I need to exclude the whole `node_modules` except `what_i_need_to_include`. Here is what I tried in my `webpack.base.babel` so far:

The first approach:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: '/node_modules/',
      include: '/node_modules/my_main_package/what_i_need_to_include',
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: options.babelQuery,
      },
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The second approach:

```js
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: '/node_modules\/(?!my_main_package/what_i_need_to_include).*/',
  ...
}
```

both times unsuccessfully.

How can I get this working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this github thread? So many ways to do it, one of them it should work for your case. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: Yes, there was a solution. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have to thank Mr. The Bear, he gave me a link with a working solution, and I will answer my question myself for sharing a solution, since very few people read the comments and this may probably would be a question for others. here is the solution:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(my_main_package\/what_i_need_to_include)\/).*/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: options.babelQuery,
      },
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Hope it might be helpful.

Comment: Helped me in 2023 :)

Answer (score 14):

It's worth noting a solution on that page that doesn't require a complex regular expression, and is technically the supported approach.

```js
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [
                // Use an object instead of a string
                {
                    test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                    // Exclude the following from the exclusion
                    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/name-of-package')
                }
            ],
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                // ...
            },
        },
    ]
},
```

Comment: Webpack 5 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796154/webpack-v5-exclude-on-exclude-no-longer-working