# Webpack v5: Exclude on exclude no longer working

Tags: webpack

I'm migrating to webpack v5 and it appears that support for exclude within exclude is removed. I don't see anything about it in the migration guide though. Any ideas?

In webpack v4, I had the following in my webpack config file:

```
        {
            test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
            exclude: [
                {
                    // Exclude node_modules from running through babel-loader
                    test: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                    // Include (exclude from the exclusion) the MYCUSTOM folder.
                    // This is needed since MYCUSTOM itself isn't run through any transpilation but offered as a straight up typescript library.
                    exclude: path.resolve(
                        __dirname,
                        "node_modules/@MYORG/MYCUSTOM"
                    )
                }
            ],
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    compact: false
                }
            }
        },
```

Now, in webpack v5 I get an error:

> configuration.module.rules[1].exclude has an unknown property 'test'. These properties are valid:
> object { and?, not?, or? }

I'm not seeing any answers in the documentation as to why this was removed and what to use instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude exclusions, use this configuration (example showing use for babel-loader and ts or js files).

```js
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
        exclude: [
          {
            // exclude all node_modules from running through babel-loader
            and: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")],
            // exception: include these node_modules
            not: [
              // add any node_modules that should be run through babel here
              path.resolve(
                rootPath,
                "node_modules/@MY_ORG/MY_PACKAGE1"
              ),
              path.resolve(
                  rootPath,
                  "node_modules/@MY_ORG/MY_PACKAGE2"
              ),
            ]
          }
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

@Scott Martin, I tried that with no success. The only thing I found to work was using exclude with "not" and "and" as shown here:

```
                exclude: [
                {
                    and: [path.resolve(rootPath, "node_modules")],
                    not: [
                        path.resolve(
                            rootPath,
                            "node_modules/my_repo"
                        )
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

Comment: this is still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

My config also had an exclude-in-exclude for the same reason, and I just ran into this issue when upgrading from Webpack 4 to 5. I have to agree, the documentation is really far too skimpy. (I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13897) asking them to add more examples!)

It seems that they've simplified the format and you specify `exclude` and `include` [conditions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition) directly. Try this:

```js
{
    test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@MYORG/MYCUSTOM"),
    // use: ...
},
```